# Being able to warn by either id or mention (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

My code runs perfectly but I want my bot to be able to warn members by either id or mention like if i want to warn i can either use id or mention.

Currently i can only warn members by mentioning. IF i use two variables then it will assign the value to wrong variable like if i give it id but the first variable is user_mention variable then it would assign it to that variable.

here is my code

```
with open('reports.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
  try:
    report = json.load(f)
  except ValueError:
    report = {}
    report['users'] = []

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx,user:discord.User, *reason:str):
    # await ctx.send(f"msg sender top role position {ctx.message.author.top_role.position} the other members top role position {user.top_role.position}")

    guild = ctx.guild
    member = ctx.guild.get_member(user.id)
    member_top_role = member.top_role
    member_top_role_position = member_top_role.position

    requester = ctx.message.author
    requester_id = ctx.guild.get_member(requester.id)
    requester_top_role = requester_id.top_role
    requester_top_role_position = requester_top_role.position

    if requester_top_role_position > member_top_role_position:
        if not reason:
            await client.say("Please provide a reason")
            return
        reason = ' '.join(reason)
        for current_user in report['users']:
            if current_user['name'] == user.name:
                current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
            break
        else:
            report['users'].append({
            'name':user.name,
            'reasons': [reason,]
            })
        with open('reports.json','w+') as f:
            json.dump(report,f)
            await ctx.send(f"<:classic_check_mark:1055182126103937155> {user.mention} has been warned!")
            await user.send(f"<:warning_icon:1055184901919494195> You have been warned from {guild.name}\n\n<:warning_icon:1055184901919494195> Resone: {reason}")
        
    elif requester_top_role_position < member_top_role_position:
        await ctx.send(f"<:failed:1055182259054985306> {user.mention} has higher role than you. You can't warn that member!")

@warn.error
async def warn_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        await ctx.send("<:failed:1055182259054985306> You don't have permission to use this command.")

    elif isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send("<:syntax:1055182220140232704> Incorrect argument | --warn <@person> <reason>")

@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warnings(ctx,user:discord.User):
  for current_user in report['users']:
    if user.name == current_user['name']:
      await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has been reported {len(current_user['reasons'])} times : {','.join(current_user['reasons'])}")
      break
  else:
    await ctx.send(f"{user.name} has never been reported")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can modify the command functin to take a string as the user, and then use the `discord.utils.get` function to try to convert the string to a `User` object.

Try it like this

```
@client.command(pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
async def warn(ctx, user: str, *reason: str):
    # Try to convert the user String to a User object
    member = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.members, mention=user)
    if not member:
        # If the argument is not a mention, try to convert it to a user ID
        try:
            user_id = int(user)
            member = ctx.guild.get_member(user_id)
        except ValueError:
            pass

    if not member:
        await ctx.send("Invalid user argument")
        return

    # Use the `name` attribute of the `Member` object instead of the `str` object
    for current_user in report['users']:
        if member.name == current_user['name']:
            current_user['reasons'].append(reason)
            break
    else:
        report['users'].append({
            'name': member.name,
            'reasons': [reason,]
        })

    with open('reports.json', 'w+') as f:
        json.dump(report, f)
    await ctx.send(f"<:classic_check_mark:1055182126103937155> {member.mention} has been warned!")
    await member.send(f"<:warning_icon:1055184901919494195> You have been warned from {guild.name}\n\")
```

Comment: That fixed that problem but now i cant append the data into the json file

Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'name'

Comment: @KiyotakaAyanokoji as stated in the comment you need to us `member` instead of `user` because User is a String an member is a User object

Comment: @KiyotakaAyanokoji I edited my Code try it like that